# How to navigate to Custom Lightning Tab (having lwc) through lightning button having recordId in parameter?

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, lightning-experience, lightning-button, lightning-tab

[image]I am trying to navigate to lightning tab which displays a lwc.
I have a custom object and in lightning I have created one button and I am passing
**/lightning/n/ComponentTab?id={!record.Id}** this in url section, where ComponentTab is lightning component tab name. Now when I click on lightning button I am able to navigate to other tab but I am not able to get the id I am passing..

What I am missing here?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `c__` prefix to your id parameter. Your button code should be something like below.

```
/lightning/n/your_custom_tab_api_name?c__id={!record.id}
```

You can look further in LWC [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_navigate_basic).

Comment: Yup thanx it worked Bilal

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you are retrieving the `id` - via pagereference? But generally when you pass values in a url in lightning now, the url variables are prefixed with `c__`

So wherever you are trying to access the `id` param, you should be referencing it as `c__id`

In the controller class in the lwc, you should access your id var like this:

```
get recordId() {
    // Derive the id from the current page state
    return (!this.currentPageReference) ? null : this.currentPageReference?.state?.c__id;
        
}
```

See [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_navigate_add_params_url) help page for more info.

Don't forget you need to include some pagereference related code:

```
import { CurrentPageReference, NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';
export default class YourClass extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
    
    currentPageReference;
    @wire(CurrentPageReference)
    setCurrentPageReference(currentPageReference) {
      this.currentPageReference = currentPageReference;
    }
```

Comment: Hii @caspar I have just added screenshot of the button properties, Please have a look and yes I am using currentPageReference and inside the state its showing null array instead of the parameters  i am passing

Comment: Also, I forgot to add the bit that @Bilal mentioned - if you don't send the id as c__id, salesforce will just remove the param.